# Given that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $(0,1)$, and $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$

Tags: calculus

> Given that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $(0,1)$, and $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, prove
>   $$\text{There exists $c_1 \lt c_2$ such that $\frac{1}{f'(c_1)}+\frac{1}{f'(c_2)} =2$}$$ and 
>   $$\text{There exists $c_1 \lt c_2$ such that $f'(c_1)f'(c_2)=1$} $$

I have already proven that there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=1$ and there exist $c_1 \lt c_2$ such that $f'(c_1)+f'(c_2)=2$. I tried using these to help to prove the existence of the above.

---

I've just learned Mean Value Theorem, Rolle's Theorem and Intermediate Value Theorem, which I've used to answer the first two parts. Given the mark allocation for these two questions, they're supposed to be easy. However, I can't seem to find my way around.

Please advise me on what I should do to simplify the problem. Thank you!

Comment: May I know where this problem comes from?

Comment: @RobertZ from one of my assignments. Probably adapted from another textbook. Maybe Spivak?

Answer (score 0):

Part 1: there is a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c)=\tfrac12$. Now apply MVT to $[0,c]$ and $[c,1]$.

Part 2: there is a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c) = 1-c$. Again apply MVT to $[0,c]$ and $[c,1]$.

Comment: Could you explain how would you continue Part 1? I simplified the problem to give $\frac{1}{f'(c_1)}+\frac{1}{f'(c_2)}=\frac{1}{2f(\frac{1}{2})(1-f(\frac{1}{2}))}$

Comment: @kevinbobbkoh If $f(c) = \tfrac12$ then there exists $c_1\in(0,c)$ such that $f'(c_1)=1/(2c)$. Also there is a $c_2\in (c,1)$ such that $f'(c_2)=1/(2-2c)$...